# Hibernate Naming Strategy not working xml bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Here i am attaching both bean definition i have tried and naming strategy i have followed. But jpa is not recognising it. Where did i do wrong?

Xml Configuration File :

```
<bean id="EntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="JpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.<package-name>.entity" />
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">jta</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy">com.hrc.commons.CustomNamingStrategy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Naming Strategy Java Code File:

```
package com.hrc.commons;

import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy;

public class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String PREFIX = "prefix_";

@Override
public String classToTableName(final String className) {
    return this.addPrefix(super.classToTableName(className));
}

@Override
public String tableName(final String tableName) {
    return this.addPrefix(super.tableName(tableName));
}

@Override
public String collectionTableName(final String ownerEntity, final String ownerEntityTable, final String associatedEntity, final String associatedEntityTable, final String propertyName) {
    return this.addPrefix(super.collectionTableName(ownerEntity, ownerEntityTable, associatedEntity, associatedEntityTable, propertyName));
}

@Override
public String logicalCollectionTableName(final String tableName, final String ownerEntityTable, final String associatedEntityTable, final String propertyName) {
    return this.addPrefix(super.logicalCollectionTableName(tableName, ownerEntityTable, associatedEntityTable, propertyName));
}

private String addPrefix(final String tableName) {
    return PREFIX + tableName;
}
```

}

I tried individual attributes and individual `jpaPropertiesMap` and `jpaProperties` too. But still no luck. Please anybody help.

I need to add `prefix_` to every entity that i found in that particular `packagesToScan` folder. so for ex: if there is any entity file defined like

```
@Entity @Table(name="student")
```

and if prefix is `"iiit"`, i need is `iiit_student` as the table name using this naming strategy. I didn't get any error regarding this. But getting table not found in the schema error only.